# Getting Mongoid from params array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

In order to **find a Root Document that contains a embedded document** using MongoID/Rails 3 I need to do my query this way:

```
QuoteRequest.where( "order_request_items._id" => BSON::ObjectID(params[:id]) ).first
```

Is there a way to query without using the BSON::ObjectID ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a MongoID/Rails user, but my guess is that you can't.

Even in the Mongo shell you have to use `ObjectId()` if you want to compare ObjectIDs. Something like this won't return any results:

```
db.foo.find({_id: "4c7ca651db48000000002277"})
```

You'll have to create an actual ObjectID from the string in order to get results:

```
db.foo.find({_id: ObjectId("4c7ca651db48000000002277")})
```

MongoID apparently doesn't automatically convert your input to ObjectIDs. But perhaps there's a way to tell MongoID which fields it should always convert to ObjectIDs? Then you would be able to omit the use of `BSON::ObjectID`.

Comment: I was thinking that MongoID should automatically convert ids into ObjectIDs. It kind of do that in Rails when you do Model.find("4c7ca651db48000000002277") but you need to  use the BSON::ObjectID(params[:id]) when doing a conditional search.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug, the ids should be automagically converted by Mongoid.  You should open a ticket on github: http://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues